# Is there any way to add box decoration to active BottomNavigationBar as an indicator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-bottomnavigation

Desired Output:

[when no BottomNavigationBarItem is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fNiN.png)

[When 1st BottomNavigationBarItem is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRqK0.png)

Source Code:

```
late int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.call, size: 150),
    Icon(Icons.camera, size: 150),
    Icon(Icons.chat, size: 150),
    Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined, size: 150)
  ];
```

```
bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            //
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF212121),
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFFFFC72C),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          type: BottomNavigationBarType
              .fixed, //for getting more than 3 default bar items
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.supervisor_account_outlined),
              label: 'Shopper',
            ),
            const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.book_outlined),
              label: 'Coupon',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Transform.scale(
                scaleX: -1,
                child: const Icon(Icons.bar_chart_outlined),
              ),
              label: 'Dashboard',
            ),
            const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_7_outlined),
              label: 'Edit Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[This is What I have Acieved So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXCi5.png)

Do reply if you found anything. Thanks for help :) in advance

[Container taking only that much as space as provided to icon widget of BottomNavigationBarItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYn6I.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use active Icon like this

```dart
const BottomNavigationBarItem(
  activeIcon: Container(
            height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.orange,
            child: Icon(Icons.supervisor_account_outlined)
           ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.supervisor_account_outlined),
              label: 'Shopper',
            ),
```

You can also add a Container to the icon of BottomNavigationBarItem and change color of container based on index

```dart
const BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Stack(
    children : [
      if(_selectedIndex == 0)
        Container( height: 50, width : 50, color: Colors.orange),
        Column(
          children: [ Icon(Icons.supervisor_account_outlined),
           Text("Shopper")
  
           ]
         ),
        ]
      ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help brother. But,
1. the active icon is giving orange color around the icon only and not the label. 
2. The named parameter 'child' isn't defined in BottomNavigationBarItem

`BottomNavigationBarItem(
  child: Column(children: [
    Stack(children: [
      if (_selectedIndex == 0)
        Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.orange),
          const Icon(Icons.supervisor_account_outlined),
    ]),
    const Text("Shopper")
    ]),
  icon: const Icon(Icons.supervisor_account_outlined)),`

Comment: Updated my answer. Also please remove active icon colour if you have added it. That's what is changing the icon colour i think

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort Brother. But the space provided to Container is limited by the space provided to Icon of BottomNavigationBarItem. Desired result is that Container's height is more than BotomNavigationBar but this is not happening. 

[Container taking only that much as space as provided to icon widget of BottomNavigationBarItem][4]

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYn6I.png

Comment: You can increase the size to 60 or 70 or add clipnone to the stack